# Blender 3.2: Leaves and animation missing - sapling tree gen

Tags: animation, sapling-addon

I've been working on making and animating a tree in Blender, using the sapling tree generator. I created the tree, added an armature and animation, and added leaves (they're rectangles with an alpha map to create a leaf shape). I haven't done anything else very advanced with the leaf materials (just a texture and color ramp). There's also an emitter modifier for falling leaves.

When I view the animation in the viewport, all looks as expected, leaves are present, and the branches move.

[image]

However, when I go to render the animation, it's missing the leaves and animation added with sapling tree gen.

[image]

I've checked and as as far as I can tell, all of the entries in scene collection are set to render, so it's a little confusion as to why they wouldn't be present in the render.

[image]

Comment: can you share the file?

Comment: Woops, thought I did initially, it should be located here: https://blend-exchange.com/b/xeLVn0Be/

Comment: @MartyFouts i was tempted to mark this Q as dup but im wondering if it is appropriate to flag such questions as duplicate even if the question appears to not be related to the commonly occuring 'show emitter' problem?

Comment: @MartyFouts The below answer (clicking show emitter to show leaves) did solve the issue, so the answer in the link you attached would work as a solution as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may believe that leafs are particles, but that's wrong. Leafs are mesh, and particle system used for generating falling leafs. So that emitter may be hidden by using this checkbox in particle settings:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that actually appears to have solved the issue of the leaves not being present, and I think with the leaves being present, I can see now that the branches are moving, I just had the animation speed and amplitude very low